# how to write this js code inside views in ruby on rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to handle this type of js on rails ? i have looked in Javascript helper but i didn't find a match for this case.

```
<li><a class="sea-green" href="javascript:chooseStyle('sea-green', 60)" title="Sea Green">Sea Green</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with jquery, something like this:

view:

```
<li><a class="sea-green" title="Sea Green">Sea Green</a></li>
```

JS file:

```
   $('.sea-green').click(function(){
        chooseStyle('sea-green', 60)
   });
```

Comment: could you please check this [link](http://previews.sunflowertheme.com/bootclean_1.1/index.html) its for the theme i am trying to use in rails , i have edited the css to load the images through the assets , and also i have added all the assets in application.rb , the page you will see i think its working with me after modifying , but for the color scheme on the left still can make it work.

Comment: if you would like to check the files of the theme i can give you link to download it and see which JS file is used by the color scheme and tell me what should i do

Comment: both of color scheme and example pattern not working with me.